# "Unable to start debugging on the web server" error message in Visual Studio 2010 and app runs fine without debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I get error message "Unable to start debugging on the web server" in  Visual Studio 2010 (Windows 7). The app works fine if running without the  debugger. I can also manually attach to the aspnet_wp.exe process and have a breakpoint hit in the app. I have debug=true in web.config.

Why do I get the error message?

Comment: Are you by chance using a location element in your web.config?

Comment: I don't have a location element. It's a website application (DotnetNuke).

Comment: Did you have the beta version of vs2010 installed? Does it work on a different machine?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this has to do with a previous instance of the debugging server of ASP.Net being open on the same port by another instance of Visual Studio, of which the current instance has no control.

It appear this can happen if VS crashes with the server open. However, [it was supposed to be fixed](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/518357/asp-net-development-server-error).